# windows phone 8.1 universal application with a background task crashes

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows phone 8.1 universal application with a background task. Every time my background task is instantiated the application crashes and none of my background application code is executed.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like you have a bug in the background task that crashes your app. If you want specific help, we need a specific question. Preferably with code pieces.

Comment: I do not believe this issue to be off topic. I am writing a C# windows phone 8.1 application and have been trying to figure out why my application kept crashing every time it tried to instantiate my background task code in the emulator. I put up this question too see if someone had this same issue

Comment: `I put up this question too see if someone had this same issue` This isn't the place to ask around. Your question contains to little information about your problem. Add code, what you've tried and show us exactly where something goes wrong as much as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a windows Universal Application Class library that implements IBackgroundTask the output type, must be set to "Windows Runtime component". If the Class library output is set to "Class library" the application will crash when trying to instantiate the background task with no exception being thrown.

To resolve in the class library goto project settings...
Select Output type and set the Output type: to "Windows Runtime Component".

This is a difficult error to diagnose since no exception is ever thrown.